# Good practices while working with multiple game engines, porting a game to a new engine

Tags: software-engineering

I have to work with multiple game engines, like

- Cocos2d
- Unity3d
- Galaxy

While working with multiple game engines, what practices should I follow?

For instance, we made a game with Cocos2d and released it on the AppStore. Now we want to port it to other platforms using Unity.

What would be the course of actions to follow?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Are you having specific problems that need to be solved? Are you using these engines in one project or do you happen to have multiple projects using one engine each?

Comment: Do you mean multiple game engines *for one game*?

Comment: @mrbinary, I have edited my question as your criteria

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou, I have edited my question as your criteria

Comment: OK so this is more about porting a game to a new engine. I think you should rework your title a bit.

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou or more specifically, about making the game easy to port to concrete engines.

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou, Yes, i have edited questions title

Comment: I think this is a bit too broad for the site. I can't imagine there is a *correct* answer to this question.

Comment: Please don't edit more questions into your question; you should think them through and if they are a good fit for the site, post them as new questions. Edits should be used only for clarification. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you're searching for with this question. It also doesn't seem game development specific; you might try wording it better and asking it on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/). Still, it's a very open-ended, discussion type question, which doesn't lend well to our Q&A format, and it'd likely be closed on SO as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest finding a common denominator of these engines. That is, if you will use a physics engine, find one that has ports already made for other environments you use. If you use a MVC approach, use a MVC framework that is either ported to other environments (pureMVC is quite popular) or that works in a similar way as other MVC frameworks you can use in other environments.

In the end it is best to decouple view components specific to game engine from rest of the code, so when porting the game you can focus on a specific part of the source.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Better untick this as an answer, this will motivate others to answer too.

Comment: Okay. I have untick the answer. I want more answers. After that i will choose the best answer.

Comment: -1 MVC will not help at all, if you port between different languages, as asker does. Besides MVC is an anti pattern when it comes to games, particularily on low end devices

Comment: Hello @MaikSemder, I didn't recommend to use MVC, I just pointed out that it would be easier to port actionscript game using pureMVC to a javascript game using pureMVC, than porting robotlegs to pureMVC and than restructuring whole code not to use injector class. I will not go into a religious war about patterns and anti-patterns, though.